# Connection to MGMNT iterface on Cisco DSC 9124-K9 lost

Tags: cisco, storage-area-network, fibre-channel

From some reasons i've lost connection to mgmnt interface in DSC9124-K9 - I cannot ping, cannot see MAC in arp.
Fabric interfaces are working well, without problems so I do not want to reset whole switch.
Is there possibility to recover this connection without restarting switch?

I didn't tried Serial option.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the cable and port the device is plugged into?

After that you will need to use the serial console to troubleshoot any further.